# What's the meaning of "assigning an empty string" in this context?

Tags: php, string, offset, fatal-error, php-7.1

I am using **PHP 7.1.0**

I come across following confusing text from the [Strings chapter of PHP Manual][1]

> **Warning** Writing to an out of range offset pads the string with spaces.
>   Non-integer types are converted to integer. Illegal offset type emits
>   **E_NOTICE**. Only the first character of an assigned string is used. As
>   of PHP 7.1.0, assigning an empty string throws a fatal error.
>   Formerly, it assigned a NULL byte.

I tried hard to understand the meaning of the clauses from the above text

> "Only the first character of an assigned string is used."

and

> "As of PHP 7.1.0, assigning an empty string throws a fatal error.
>   Formerly, it assigned a NULL byte."

I don't understand at all the first statement from the above two statements.

For second statement I tried to understand it through actual code. So, for it I wrote following code but I'm not sure whether this code demonstrates the thing which the statement from the manual want to say. Following is my code snippet. From it, tell me whether I'm understanding the statement correctly and have wrote the code correctly or not to demonstrate the meaning of the statement from the PHP manual. If I'm doing it wrong please correct my code accordingly to be in compliance with the statement from the PHP manual.

**Code Snippet:**

```
<?php 
$rootbeer = 'A & W';
$rootbeer[] = 'N';
?>
```

**Output in PHP 7.1.0:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in hello.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in hello.php on line 3
```

**Output in PHP 5.6.30 :**

```
Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in hello.php on line 3
```

From the above two outputs I don't see anywhere in **PHP 5.6.30** that  **NULL byte** is getting assigned to something. As with the both the versions I'm getting almost the same output, same error.

Please demonstrate the difference between outputs in **PHP 7.1.0** and PHP **5.6.30**. So that it would be better for me to understand the differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't assigning an empty string nor are you using an out of range offset. I believe the code you want to try looks like this:

```
<?php
$rootbeer = 'A & W';
$rootbeer[7] = '';
echo $rootbeer;
```

This will work fine in PHP 5.6 and output the padded string mentioned in the documentation.

In PHP 7.1+, you will get a warning

> PHP Warning:  Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in yourfile.php on line 3

and the string will not be altered.

Comment: I know this thing. In the manual it's been clearly mentioned that  > "As of PHP 7.1.0, assigning an empty string throws a fatal error. But in your code it's merely giving a Warning. Your code doesn't demonstrate that a fatal error being generated.

Comment: That is indeed a mystery. I had a look at the source of the [PHP interpreter](https://github.com/php/php-src/) and this warning was indeed introduced in version 7.1. So, maybe the documentation just doesn't agree with the implementation? It strikes me as a weird coincidence that the behaviour change happened at the right version just not the way it's described.

Comment: Thanks for your close observation. Would you please demonstrate the statement "As of PHP 7.1.0, applying the empty index operator on a string throws a fatal error. Formerly, the string was silently converted to an array." with some suitable cod example? Thanks once again. I'm waiting for your reply.

Comment: My point is that that fatal error doesn't seem to exist. While the file https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.27/Zend/zend_execute.c has no warning, yet, you will find the warning quoted above in https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1.0/Zend/zend_execute.c . There is no fatal error in that same function and I would expect it in that place.

Comment: Thanks jsfan. Just help me out with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030816/whats-the-difference-in-the-output-of-two-different-php-versions-i-e-php-5-6