# What's the difference in the output of two different PHP versions (i.e. PHP 5.6.30 and PHP 7.1.0) after applying the empty index operator on a string?

Tags: php, string, offset, fatal-error, php-7.1

I'm using **PHP 7.1.0**

I come across following text from the [Strings chapter from PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) :

> **Note:** As of PHP 7.1.0, applying the empty index operator on a string
>   throws a fatal error. Formerly, the string was silently converted to
>   an array.

So, I tried the below code and observed the output with **PHP 5.6.30** and PHP **7.1.0** but in both the cases I got almost the same output i.e. the **Fatal error**.

I nowhere seen in the output of **PHP 5.6.30** that the string is silently getting converted to an array anywhere which I expected to happen if the text from the manual is to be believed.

The code I wrote is as below :

```
<?php
$rootbeer = 'A & W';
$rootbeer[] = 'T';
?>
```

**Output in PHP 5.6.30 :**

```
Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in hello.php on line 3
```

**Output in PHP 7.1.0 :**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in hello.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in hello.php on line 3
```

If I've misunderstood the statement and written wrong code please correct me.

Also, let me know how the below additional part is getting displayed in the output for **PHP 7.1.0**

```
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in hello.php on line 3
```

Thank You.

Comment: The TL;DR difference is that PHP 7.0 introduced catchable errors. Wrap your statement in a `try/catch` block for `Throwable` and you will get just the error, and not an  "Uncaught" exception

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php read manual

Comment: @Machavity : How my question does relate to the question you suggested? I'm not asking about the details of errors and exceptions. I'm specifically asking about the correct interpretation of the statement from the PHP manual. According to that statement I should get different output for two different PHP versions which I mentioned in my question. Also, nowhere I can see the silent conversion to array in output of version 5.6.30. So, I kindly request you to remove the tag of Duplicate Question from my question. Thank You.

Comment: @SerialKisser : The wording in the docs is a bit weird but what changed in 7.1 is when you have an empty string and then access it that way: http://3v4l.org/V5YJa

Comment: I've fixed the docs to read `As of PHP 7.1.0, applying the empty index operator on an empty string throws a fatal error. Formerly, the empty string was silently converted to an array.`

Comment: @JoeWatkins : The same correction is needed on page https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying